# Sidebar links in google map not loading from dynamically generated markers

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-markers, sidebar

I’ve got a google map loading which plots markers via JSON and a loop – all fine with this so far.

However, I’m also trying to generate sidebar links from the markers with a function ‘**buildSidebar()**’ which has its own loop but this function is breaking the map. I stripped it back and both versions are in the script, commented out.

Could anyone advise where the sidebar building element is wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

There’s a fiddle of this which – ahem – also won’t load (thought I’d followed everything to get g maps loading in fiddle …): http://jsfiddle.net/4mTpt/

Thanks in advance.

Here's the script:

```
(function () {

  window.onload = function() {

    // Create new map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-02"), {
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

    var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // Create the JSON data
    var json = [
      {
          "title": "Dalston Kingsland",
          "lat": 51.548148,
          "lng": -0.075674,
          "description": "<strong>Dalston Kingsland</strong> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet," + 
          "consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet" + 
          " <em>AAA dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</em>"
      },
      {
          "title": "Hackney Central",
          "lat": 51.547105,
          "lng": -0.056031,
          "description": "<strong>Hackney Central</strong> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet," + 
          "consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet" + 
          " <em>BBB dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</em>"
      },
      {
          "title": "Bethnal Green Station",
          "lat": 51.523917,
          "lng": -0.059541,
          "description": "<strong>Bethnal Green Station</strong> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet," + 
          "consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet" + 
          " <em>CCC dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</em>"
      },
      {
          "title": "Old Street Station",
          "lat": 51.525528,
          "lng": -0.088185,
          "description": "<strong>Old Street Station</strong> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet," + 
          "consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet" + 
          " <em>CCC dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</em>"
      }
    ]

    // Create global infoWindow object for all markers
    //var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      //content: contentString,
      maxWidth: 250
    });

    // Loop through the JSON data
    for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {
      var data = json[i],
      latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);

      // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        title: data.title
      });

      //function buildSidebar() {
        //for (var i=0; i<marker.length; i++) {
          //if (marker[i].getVisible()) {
            //sidebarHtml += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + marker[i].myname + '<\/a><br>';
            //}
          //}
        //for (var i=0; i<marker.length; i++) {
          /*if (marker[i].getVisible()) {
            sidebarHtml += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + marker[i].myname + '<\/a><br>';
            }
          //}
        document.getElementById("tabs").innerHTML = sidebarHtml;
      }*/

      markerBounds.extend(latLng);

      // Create a closure to retain correct data.
      (function(marker, data) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
          infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
      })(marker, data);
    }

  map.fitBounds(markerBounds);

  }

})();
```

Comment: Did you look at the javascript errors your code generates when the buildSidebar function is put back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. there is no "marker" array in your code; to use an array of google.maps.Marker objects in HTML click events, that array needs to be available in the global scope.
2. there is no "myclick" function in your code, can be replaced by google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
3. there is no .myname property anywhere, you probably want to use .title

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_sidebar.html)

```
var gmarkers = [];
(function () {

  window.onload = function() {

    // Create new map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-02"), {
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

    var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // Create the JSON data
    var json = [
      {
          "title": "Dalston Kingsland",
          "lat": 51.548148,
          "lng": -0.075674,
          "description": "<strong>Dalston Kingsland</strong> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet," + 
          "consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet" + 
          " <em>AAA dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</em>"
      },
      {
          "title": "Hackney Central",
          "lat": 51.547105,
          "lng": -0.056031,
          "description": "<strong>Hackney Central</strong> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet," + 
          "consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet" + 
          " <em>BBB dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</em>"
      },
      {
          "title": "Bethnal Green Station",
          "lat": 51.523917,
          "lng": -0.059541,
          "description": "<strong>Bethnal Green Station</strong> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet," + 
          "consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet" + 
          " <em>CCC dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</em>"
      },
      {
          "title": "Old Street Station",
          "lat": 51.525528,
          "lng": -0.088185,
          "description": "<strong>Old Street Station</strong> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet," + 
          "consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet" + 
          " <em>CCC dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</em>"
      }
    ]

    // Create global infoWindow object for all markers
    //var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      //content: contentString,
      maxWidth: 250
    });

    // Loop through the JSON data
    for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {
      var data = json[i],
      latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);

      // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        title: data.title
      });
      gmarkers.push(marker);
      markerBounds.extend(latLng);

      // Create a closure to retain correct data.
      (function(marker, data) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
          infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
      })(marker, data);
    }

  map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
  buildSidebar();
  }
      function buildSidebar() {
        var sidebarHtml = "";                         
        for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
          if (gmarkers[i].getVisible()) {
            sidebarHtml += '<a href="javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[' + i + '],\'click\')">' + gmarkers[i].title + '<\/a><br>';
            }
          }
        document.getElementById("tabs").innerHTML = sidebarHtml;
      }


})();
```